# Make virtualbox not capture keyboard/mouse

Tags: windows, virtualbox, centos

I have virtualbox on Windows 7. The guests are CentOS. The guests do have guest extensions, but do not have X. And while I can mount a shared folder, the window (with a root console in it) still "captures" keyboard and mouse when clicked.

I have to disable that in settings every run, and I'd like to disable that by default. With capturing disabled in runtime settings, Alt+Tab on the keyboard works on the host while data entry still works on the guest. And the mouse moves freely. (I don't expect to use the mouse on the guest at all).

I found a workaround for the mouse by setting "USB Tablet" in System > Motherboard; then the cursor disappears when it is over the window, but there is no capturing. But I found no way to disable capturing the keyboard. I would appreciate if anyone could point me to such a way.

Comment: What about using the `Host` key? And if your keyboard misses a `[Right-Ctrl]` key, change the key in the options

Comment: The Host key works but having to use it every time is annoying. So I'd like to disable the feature.

Comment: Why do you click at all if you don't want to have the guest focused? Why not run the guest headless and connect on demand via ssh?

Comment: I am not sure how to connect to the guest via SSH if it is on built-in NAT and/or on an internal network - and all my guests are like that. I have one guest with X installed (and therefore no capturing, as guest utilities are installed on all guests); I could theoretically use that to SSH into other guests, but this sounds a bit like overkill when all I want is to switch freely across a few console-only guests.

Comment: The fact that after all these years, you still don't have the option (let alone a simple one) to completely disable mouse capture in VirtualBox is truly atrocious.